# How to reload just a div inside the page, not load a new page into the div, just reload it

Tags: jquery, function

I am using this function to load a content from another page into my `<div>`:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() { 
   $("#refresh").bind("click", function() {
      $("#Container").load("Image_rotate.html")    
      });
   });
 </script>

<h2>Looking for</h2>      
<div id="Container"></div>   
</div><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="refresh">click</a>
```

But i just want to refresh my div 'Container' and not load a new content from a external page, is it possible?

Comment: what's the difference between refresh and reload the content? what do you mean with "refresh my div"?

Comment: i think he means update the divs.

Comment: @Raminson. I think he meant revert to the initial state... ?

Comment: @gdoron uhm, yes, he meant so, let's ask him? what do you mean?

Comment: Hi all, good morning, for example if i press F5 i will refresh (reload) all my page, but i want just to refresh my div "Container", i want to create a new button to do this. Sorry i am still learning about jquery. Thanks

Comment: this doesn't really clarify your question. try to read your question and my first comment

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="hiddenDiv"></div>  
<div id="Container"></div>
```

**Code:**

```
$('#hiddenDiv').html($("#Container"));

$("#refresh").bind("click", function() { 
    $("#Container").html($('#hiddenDiv').html())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#refresh").bind("click", function() {
   $("#Container").load("Image_rotate.html", function(response, status, xh) {
      $(this).html(response);  // if response is html
   })    
});
```